# Android toolchain - X Android license status unknown. showing error caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio

I am trying to setup android studio but here showing an error image where I am getting error
[image: 1]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your errors and code as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's requested here not to to use images for this purpose, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)* may also help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to android studio

1. open SDK manager
2. under SDK tools uncheck hide obsolete packages at the bottom
3. then you should see an option called Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)
4. check it and apply and let the studio download the package
5. once done run the command flutter doctor and it should now prompt you to run flutter doctor --android-licenses once you run the license command accept all licenses by hitting y and it should solve the problem

try this.

Or you will install jdk 8
and after that run following command

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Comment: not able to find sdk tools?? in sdk file i have file cmd-line tools, build-tools, platform-tools,  and tool....,,,,, which one sdk tool

Comment: yes i already checked that sdk tools obsolete

Comment: @ShivShankar, please install cmd-line-tool