# flutter doctor --android-licenses is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, dart

`flutter doctor --android-licenses` after running this command in the command prompt it says 'C:\Users\Username' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file instead of saying flutter doctor --android-licenses is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

[image: flutter doctor --android-licenses after running this command in the command prompt it says 'C:\Users\Username' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file instead of saying flutter doctor --android-licenses is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.]

Comment: Rename the folder by removing the parentheses "(" and ")" and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You don`t have android license accept please accept it run below command on your terminal hope it help to you

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Comment: i have already done it but it says 'C:\Users\Prangon' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. please check the picture.

Comment: Ok try this command on flutter console (You found in installed flutter directory flutter.consol.bat file ) or change your flutter installation directory

Comment: @CoderPs Try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68204105/13997210) hope it work

Comment: thank you for your concern but it's still the same problem. How can I find it solution, I am clueless. :'(