# Unable to locate Android SDK error when running flutter doctor license

Tags: javascript, android, flutter

I already had android studio and added flutter. When i try to run the Flutter doctor license command line its is showing "android STK" error

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


PS D:\SAMBURU CONSULTANTS\Flutter Projects\samburu_1> flutter doctor --android-licenses
Unable to locate Android SDK.
```

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68708242/13997210) answer hope its help to you

Answer (score 0):

Add Android SDK to PATH, like this:

[image]

After this restart your shell and try again with flutter doctor